Specific games randomly crash multiple times an hour with DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG
Apparently this is a well-known issue that does not have a one-size-fits-all fix, but after hours of research I have still not found anyone mention something peculiar I have noticed. I have a new PC, with a i5-13600KF and a XFX Merc RX 7800XT on a MSI PRO B760M-A (Windows 10 x64 pro), and so far I have played 4 games:

Star Citizen: runs fine. Meh performance (40fps with occasional plummets in 1080p) but I don't think it's related.
Hellblade 1, was freezing to a point it was unplayable using DirectX12, but ran flawlessly when I switched to DirectX11 using the program's arguments.
Life is strange 2, ran perfectly.
Ghost of Tsushima: runs "easy" with ample margin in all metrics (temps between 40 and 60°C, GPU usage at 40%, VRAM at 60%) until it completely crashes with DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG randomly but very often (today, roughly every 5min sometimes the game can even autosave). Could be anywhere, anytime, generally not twice at the exact same location when I pick up where I left off. What is "peculiar" that I didn't hear about anywhere else, is that I've noticed the GPU usage shoots to 100% right when the bug occurs while everything else stays the same.

Do you think it could be a hardware issue?
I have tried updating my Radeon drivers to 24.10.1, adding -dx11 as an argument to the game shortcut, disabled XMP, turned off upscaling. None of that works.

A new computer running Windows 10? Did you downgrade it, or it is "new to you", or something else? It could be a GPU issue, and the way to tell would be to swap in a different card and see if the problems persist or go away.

I just hate Windows 11's settings pages (and the fact that it's like that because making it simple and beautiful took priority), that's all. Unfortunately I don't have another GPU to throw in that can run these games even in low settings.

Then I would recommend you pursue warranty service.

I think I fixed it. I had seen on a forum that someone had fixed it by downgrading to Radeon drivers 24.4.1 so I used the AMD cleanup tool to uninstall Adrenalin 24.10.1 and installed the previous Adrenalin + drivers pack 24.4.1 and I was able to play yesterday and today respectively 1h10 and 2h50 without any crash (stopped on my own, not because of the crash). Fingers crossed. Hope this helps!

If someone has the same problem, sees my post, and wonders if it did fix it, be sure I'll write here if it didn't. So far so good.
